# 'MKMapRectIsNull' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.isNull'

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview, swift4.2

So in updating to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2, of course I had to make a lot of changes in my project to update the syntax. I was able to rectify all issues except for one. I'm getting an error that says: **'MKMapRectIsNull' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.isNull'**. I did the obvious thing of trying replacing **MKMapRectIsNull** with **MKMapRect.isNull**, but that generates another error which says: **Instance member 'isNull' cannot be used on type 'MKMapRect'**. Here's some more context:

```
var zoomRect = MKMapRect.null
    for annotation in map.annotations {
        let annotationPoint = MKMapPoint(annotation.coordinate)
        let pointRect = MKMapRect(x: annotationPoint.x, y: annotationPoint.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        if (MKMapRect.isNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect
        } else {
            zoomRect = zoomRect.union(pointRect)
        }
    }
    map.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 40, bottom: 40, right: 40), animated: true)
```

Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the condition `if (MKMapRect.isNull(zoomRect))` you need to change that to `if (zoomRect.isNull)`

You cannot check the condition for `MKMapRect` type, only an instantiated object of that type.

Comment: But now MKMapRect.null is a static property, the problem is still there.

Comment: @echo, yes in this example it would still be there, but I'm thinking that it was just for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this situation, how will you initialize zoomRect like before "var zoomRect = MKMapRect.null" since MKMapRect.null is a static property now. Thanks again.